# Por que "Teiú" tem acento?

Tags: acentuação

Monossílabos tônicos e oxítonas terminadas em "I" e "U", não possuem acento.

Temos *Pacu*, que não recebe acento.

Eu vejo *teiú* como uma oxítona terminada em "U", logo, não deveria receber acento.

Onde estou errando no meu entendimento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[***Teiú*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/teiu) leva acento para indicar que o ***u*** não forma ditongo com a vogal que o precede; ou seja, a divisão silábica é *tei.ú* e não *te.iu*. O ***u*** de *Pacu* não leva acento porque não é precedido de vogal. O ***u*** de *pediu* não leva acento porque forma ditongo com o ***i:** -diu* é uma única sílaba, e não duas. Já [*baú* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ba%C3%BA) leva também acento porque são duas sílabas, *ba.ú*, e não um ditongo (não rima com *pau*). Do mesmo modo, temos um ditongo em *pais*, plural de *pai*, e duas sílabas em *país*.

Esta regra vem no [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 (Portal da Língua Portuguesa)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990):

> **Base X: da acentuação das vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas *i* e *u* das palavras oxítonas e paroxítonas**
>
> 1. As vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas *i* e *u* das palavras oxítonas e paroxítonas levam acento agudo quando antecedidas de uma vogal com que não formam ditongo e desde de que não constituam sílaba com a eventual consoante seguinte, excetuando o caso de *s: adaís* (pl. de *adail*), *aí, atraí* (de *atrair*), *baú, caís* (de *cair*), *Esaú, jacuí, Luís, país*, etc.; *alaúde, amiúde, Araújo, Ataíde, atraiam* (de *atrair*), *atraísse* (id.), *baía, balaústre, cafeína, ciúme, egoísmo, faísca, faúlha, graúdo, influíste* (de *influir*), *juízes, Luísa, miúdo, paraíso, raízes, recaída, ruína, saída, sanduíche*, etc.

Comment: Esclarecedor, voltarei aos estudos da língua portuguesa. Obrigado!

Comment: Em outras palavras, sem acento "teiú" ficaria parecido com "caiu" do verbo cair (ficaria íu em vez de iú). Com um detalhe: isso só vale para o fim da palavra. O acordo ortográfico removeu o acento em feiura, que seguiria o mesmo princípio, mas é paroxítona. Talvez nem exista palavra paroxítona com "e-íu" / "a-íu" e por isso removeram o acento.

Comment: @marcus, verdade, "teiu" ficaria parecido com "caiu". A regra ortográfica vai além do que eu expliquei. O ponto 4 da mesma base diz: "Prescinde-se do acento agudo nas vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas i e u das palavras paroxítonas, quando elas estão precedidas de ditongo: baiuca, boiuno [...]" (provavelmente pela razão que adiantas). Por isso não há acento em "feiura". Em Portugal já era assim antes do AO90.